# Problem with embedding activemq to jboss application server

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-classic

I'm totally a newbie in Java Enterprise and I have a lot stuff yet to learn. Right now I'm working which involves JMS using JBoss and ActiveMQ. An application sends messages to queues in JBoss and my goal is to access those messages using any message broker (in this case I tried to use ActiveMQ). So I think it's better for me to embed ActiveMQ to JBoss. I used the link below as the guidance :

http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html

I followed every single steps in the guide except that I used JBoss 4.2.3 and ActiveMQ 5.1.1. If this problem results from the different version of the tools, I think I can't help it out because other versions seem does not work on my machine. When I run JBoss to test whether the embedding is working or not, I can't see anything running on port localhost:61616 which is the default port for ActiveMQ, although JBoss seems run well. My question is :

1. Is any one know how to fix this? Or has anyone ever experienced such problem?
2. Is there any way to access queue in Jboss?

If this question is pretty ambiguous or need more details, let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any instructions based on JBoss 4.0.x are going to be seriously out of date by now, even for 4.2.x

Comment: I do have the same opinion about that. Actually I also tried a letter version of JBoss but for strange reason it does not work. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure the embedded broker is started (transport vm://localhost) which results in a working JMS broker for that VM. But this broker isn't reachable from outside (via tcp or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error in the log when launching jboss? I managed to make it work with Jboss 4.2 and ActiveMQ 5.4, and once integrated it only gives you a small hint that is working correctly with some info message saying "broker started in port ..." .

Also you can try to use the sample producers and receivers in ActiveMQ to test if the queue is working correctly.

If you still have problems I can try to help